# HP ProLiant ML110 G2 stops working when upgrading RAM

Tags: boot, memory, hp-proliant

This an old spare server I use for a Minecraft server and a web server.
It current has 2.5GB of RAM. I recently purchased 4GB (4x1GB) of new RAM and when I installed them, the server would not boot. The fan starts, and there are no non-green lights on the motherboard, but it doesn't actually boot.

The current RAM is PC3200 400MHz ECC CL3, and the [RAM I purchased](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2GB-PC3200-DDR-184PIN-400MHZ-ECC-Reg-2-X1GB-SAMSUNG-RAM-MEMORY-LIFETIME-WARR-/310417157928) is the same, as far as I can tell. Is there anything I can do to get the server to boot? I've tried only using 2 of the new chips, and I've tried different combinations, but none of them have been successful.

Edit: I've just noticed that one of the current pieces of RAM is PC3200U and the rest just say PC3200, whereas the new RAM is all PC3200R. Is this a problem?

Memory controller information from `dmidecode`:

```
Handle 0x0005, DMI type 5, 24 bytes
Memory Controller Information
    Error Detecting Method: 8-bit Parity
    Error Correcting Capabilities:
            None
    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 1024 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 4096 MB
    Supported Speeds:
            70 ns
            60 ns
    Supported Memory Types:
            SDRAM
    Memory Module Voltage: 3.3 V
    Associated Memory Slots: 4
            0x0006
            0x0007
            0x0008
            0x0009
    Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
            Unknown
```

Current memory information from `dmidecode`:

```
Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM1
        Bank Connections: 0 1
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM2
        Bank Connections: 2 3
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM3
        Bank Connections: 0 1
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 512 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
        Socket Designation: DIMM4
        Bank Connections: 2 3
        Current Speed: Unknown
        Type: DIMM SDRAM
        Installed Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
        Error Status: OK
```

Comment: The sticks you bought that contain an R are registered ram modules. The sticks you currently have in there sound like they're unbuffered ram. It makes a big difference. Sounds like your board may not support registered ecc. Check the documentation on your server.

Comment: Yeah, the specs specify unbuffered, damn. Is there any way I could have avoided this? I looked at the `dmidecode` output to figure out what kind of RAM to purchase in the first place.

Comment: Usually un-buffered ecc is the safe bet in server memory, if you're not sure what it uses and can't find motherboard specs or a manual on your server.

Comment: @DanielGibbs  You could have avoided it by checking the manual first.  Lesson for next time.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yea. I did check it actually, but I wasn't aware of the difference between registered and un-buffered RAM. Oh well, I know now.

Comment: @DanielGibbs  Ah, that too.  But hey, better to learn the lesson on 20 bucks worth of RAM than a few hundred bucks worth.  As far as learning experiences go, you got off for practically nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [HP's documentation on the ProLiant ML110 G2](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12161_div/12161_div.HTML#Memory) it doesn't support Registered ECC RAM, which is what you bought and are trying to install. You need to use Un-buffered ECC RAM, which is what you previously had in there.